# Is there a Mistake in this article of Barret et al.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, summation, summation-method

In their article ["On the spectral radius of a {0,1) Matrix Related to Mertens' Function"](https://core.ac.uk/reader/82520013), Barret et al. assert an inequality just at the end of p. 156. 
Apparently, this inequality comes from the Abel summation formula applied to

$C(n, k+1) = \sum_w ( C(w, k) - C(w, k-1)) ([n/w] - 1)$,

which yields in this case to

$C(n,k+1) = \sum_w C(w,k) ([n/w] - [n/(w+1)])$.

And apparently, they allow themselves to replace the term $[n/w]-[n/(w+1)]$ by $n/w - n/(w+1)$, upon transforming the equality into an inequality. 
That is, they consider that

$[n/w]-[n/(w+1)] \leq n/w - n/(w+1)$.

But this is false, as can be seen for example with n = 10 and w = 3 or n = 15 and w = 3.  Am I missing something?

Comment: I can't see what you say happens. What I see at the bottom of page 156 is that they have on the left hand $$\left[c(w,k)-c(w,k-1)\right]\left(\left\lfloor \frac nw\right\rfloor-1\right)$$ and apparently they evaluate this as less than or equal $$c(w,k)\left(\frac nw-\frac n{w+1}\right)$$ This doesn't look like what you wrote...

Comment: I am trying to explain this inequality: In my opinion, they first apply an Abel transform to the first expression you wrote, and then mistakenly remove the "brackets". See my question for more details.

Comment: I did read your question. I just can't see why you think that "they consider" that inequality.

Comment: I have edited this question to make it more understandable.

Comment: Are you sure it yields what you say it does? Because if you are then they obviously have a mistake, and a rather big one, with that inequality, as you show with the values of $\;n,\,w\;$ that you give as example.

Comment: You mean after the Abel summation formula ? yes I am sure.

Comment: Well, then it is a mistake, clearly...unless the nature of $\;c(n,w)\;$ is such that it makes it true in cases like $\;n=10,\,w=3\;$ and etc.

Comment: Are you *sure* it "yields in this case to" what you wrote? namely, what about the $-1$ in the original term -- are you certain they don't first "use it" to get$$
\sum_w (c(w,k) - c(w,k-1))\left(\lfloor n/w\rfloor - 1\right) \leq \sum_w (c(w,k) - c(w,k-1)) \frac{n}{w}  $$ and **then** do the Abel transform?

Comment: Your are right. They performed the inequality before Abel transform (the -1 term isn't even necessary). How did not I think about that! That's the answer. thx. (Can you write it as an answer please)? Note: They still don't show that C(w,k)-C(w, k-1) is positive, which is necessary for this argument. Anyway, I think that's the answer.

Comment: @MikeTeX Why do you need non-negativity when applying the Abel summation argument to $\sum_{w} c(w,k) \cdot \frac{n}{w}$?

Comment: No, I need non negativity to assert the inequality before Abel transform. Anyway, non negativity can be proved easily by induction using the given formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key here is to perform the two steps (Abel transform, and dealing with the floors) in the other order.

Namely, first, handle the floors:
$$
\sum_{w} c(w,k) \left( \left\lfloor \frac{n}{w} \right\rfloor - 1\right)
\leq \sum_{w} c(w,k) \cdot \frac{n}{w}
$$
and *then* perform the Abel transform. This way, you avoid the troublesome (and, indeed, false) inequality at the end.